# Supabase update with row level policies

Tags: row-level-security, supabase

**I am not able to update a row which has role level policy enabled**

My table has row level policies on insert and update as follow :

```
create policy "Allow individual insert access" on public.quotes for insert with check ( auth.uid() = created_by );

create policy "Allow individual update access" on public.quotes for update with check ( auth.uid() = created_by );
```

my insert function works fine once user is logged in :

```
export const addQuote = async (user_id, content) => {
try {
let body = await supabase
  .from("quotes")
  .insert([{ created_by: user_id, content: content }]);
return body;
} catch (error) {
console.log("error", error);
}
};
```

my update function works fine without row level policy :

```
export const updateQuote = async (quote_id, user_id, new_content) => {
try {
let body = await supabase
  .from("quotes")
  .update([{ created_by: user_id, content: new_content }])
  .eq("id", quote_id);
return body;
} catch (error) {
console.log("error in updateQuote", error);
}
};
```

But when turning on RLS the response is 404 and the row is not updated.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

I change the row level policy from *with check* to *using*, and it is working as intended.

```
create policy "Allow individual update access" on public.quotes for update using( auth.uid() = created_by );
```

<strike>update with check</strike> ---> update using

Comment: This helped me too. "Update" policies require a "using" clause that evaluates to a boolean

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have extra `[]` around your data. Could you try it without it?

```js
let body = await supabase
  .from("quotes")
  .update({ created_by: user_id, content: new_content })
  .eq("id", quote_id);
```

Comment: Indeed, i removed the array but it did not help. My toe level policy was faulty. Check my answer.

Comment: @Olivier Nice! Glad to hear that you were able to get it working!